# Google online Storage method

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have been doing a bit of testing on image ML (machine learning) with OnePanel and I have been using my local PC,which I would like to move to Google Cloud Platform (GCP),I usually have about 400 new images to run though ML, The code that runs does ML and Downloads the image from web is written in Python.

My question is which Google storage Should I use Cloud FlieStore, Cloud Store, or what else they have. Also, Ideally the Python code should be able to directly sent the download images on Cloud (or download to local then upload then I will delete from local). The images are quite small size (100 images is 15MB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is unstructured, then it breaks down to two options:

If you do not need Mobile SDKs then [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/?&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=latam-MX-all-es-dr-skws-all-all-trial-e-dr-1007178-LUAC0009359&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_346533890558-ADGP_SKWS%20%7C%20Multi%20~%20Storage%20%7C%20Cloud%20Storage-KWID_43700043798699838-kwd-325804706764-userloc_1010043&utm_term=KW_cloud%20storage-ST_Cloud%20Storage&gclid=CMeKxeyev-MCFQK0ZQodRv0Drw) is the best option, if you need Mobile SDKs then [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage). Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: It does answer it, is there any limitation (other than drive actual storage which I have unlimited) i.e api requests and stuff like this on using Cloud Storage?

Comment: There is no restriction on bucket/object creation per se, the storage is unlimited, but there are certain restrictions on buckets/objects creation rate, 5TB size of objects created, etc.. you can refer to the [Cloud Storage Quotas and Limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas) for more details.